# SimpleFTPSample - incorrect login if username has whitespace

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ftp, whitespace

in the [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) by apple, there is the problem that if the username used to log into the FTP has a whitespace it gives an error message. It is possible to log into an FTP with a username that has a whitespace, since with `filezilla` i am able to log in. How must/can this sample be edited in order to work with whitespaces in the username?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SimpleFTPSample from Apple, the ftp URL is used to provide the user name and password.

Something like:

```
CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef) [NSURL urlWithString:@"ftp://username:password@host/folder/"];
CFReadStreamRef stream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, url);
```

But you can provide them explicitly

```
CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef) [NSURL urlWithString:@"ftp://host/folder/"];
CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, url);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(stream, kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName, CFSTR("user name"));
CFReadStreamSetProperty(stream, kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword, CFSTR("password"));
```

In my experience, this works when there is a white spaces in the "user name"